# OrientDB SQL -traverse records

Tags: orientdb

example:

vertex:`A,B,C,D`

edge：`DOWN`

```
A-------(DOWN)--->B-----(DOWN)---->C-----(DOWN)---->D
```

I want to the relust like this:

```
$depth | parent_name | name
-------+-------------+-----    
0      | A           | A
1      | A           | B
2      | B           | C
3      | C           | D
```

help me!!!

Comment: Hi, which version are you using? Thx

Comment: Orientdb:2.2.26

Answer (score 0):

i think you only use one edge. 
in your case You could use the traverse sql with depth.
for more information you could read this doc.
https://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Traverse.html